# Adding new git into AOSP repo

Tags: android, git, android-source, repo

I created a new device `mydevice/` under `$AOSP_ROOT/device/`. I am trying to add the git into `$AOSP_ROOT/.repo` for local tracking purpose, I found it extremely useful if I can see the changes when performing a `repo status` or `repo diff`. These are the steps I tried:

1. perform `git init` at `mydevice` folder, leave changes uncommitted
2. Add the project into `$AOSP_ROOT/.repo/manifest.xml`

Unfortunately, when I performs `repo status` my project is not reflected in the output. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say `$HOME` is `/home/consy/` and `$AOSP_ROOT` is `/home/consy/aosp/`.

```
#init a local bare repo as the remote repo of `mydevice`
cd $AOSP_ROOT/device/
git init mydevice
git commit --allow-empty -m 'init repository'
cd $HOME
git clone $AOSP_ROOT/device --bare -- mydevice.git
cd $AOSP_ROOT/device
rm -rf mydevice

#create .repo/local_manifests (this is a feature of repo)
mkdir -p $AOSP_ROOT/.repo/local_manifests

#create a manifest under `local_manifests`.
#You can name it whatever you like except that the manifest's content should be like:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest>
  <remote fetch="file:///home/consy/" name="this"/>
  <!-- it allows only one "default" in the manifests that take effect -->
  <!-- so, do not define the "default" element here -->
  <project name="mydevice" path="device/mydevice"/>
</manifest>
```

Now when you run `repo sync`, the project(s) defined in the local manifest will be added into `$AOSP_ROOT` as extra projects. You can use repo commands like `repo status` to manipulate these extra projects. The repository will be cloned from `/home/consy/mydevice.git` and be checked out to `$AOSP_ROOT/device/mydevice`. After you make new commits under `$AOSP_ROOT/device/mydevice`, you can run `git push this <ref>:<ref>` to upload the commits to `/home/consy/mydevice.git`. Later, when you think it's ready to publish this new repository to a real host like Github or your own Gerrit, you can add a new remote pointing to Github or Gerrit and push through it. Then add the project definition `<project name="mydevice" path="device/mydevice"/>` into the main manifest you use when `repo init`, commit the change, and push to the remote manifest repository. After that, you can remove the local manifest under `$AOSP_ROOT/.repo/local_manifests` in order to avoid a duplicate-project error.

As to the the local manifest feature, see  `Local Manifests` at https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.md. If the link can't be accessed to, google `repo manifest format`. The doc is also available under `.repo/repo/docs`.

Comment: I'm getting a `fatal: duplicate default in /home/XXXXX/aosp/.repo/manifest.xml` - How can I fix this?

Comment: @HyperionX Search `.repo/manifest.xml` to see if there are two or more  `<default remote="foo" revision="bar" ... />`